# Maatwebsite, export to XLSX giving currepted data in Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using below code to Export into .xlsx using package `maatwebsite/excel`

```
$fileName = 'Stats-GroupID_' . $groupId . '-' . time() . '.xlsx';

return Excel::download($statsExport->setGroupId($groupId), $fileName);
```

The output is filled with broken characters: � as shown in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

I tried `ob_end_clean();` It was working, but I'm not sure whether it will break anything across my projects, so don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling ob_start method after ob_end_clean as follows

```
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
```